# how can i delete all the commented sections from web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I want to delete all the commented section i.e between `<!---->` from the config file using c#.

I am having a large file of web.config with a lot of comments

Comment: Please edit your question and elaborate your issue in detail.

Answer (score 3):

Basically `Web.config` is an xml file.

So all you need to do is read your `Web.config` in `XMLDocument` with `IgnoreComments` setting. This will leave out all comments. Then save the `InnerXML` of `XMLDocument` to `Web.config`.

Here is the code

```
string path = @"D:\web.config";
string fileContents = string.Empty;

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.IgnoreComments = true;

using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings))
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    xDoc.Load(reader);
    fileContents = xDoc.InnerXml;    
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, fileContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

comment are in `<!--    -->` tag.
If you comment config main tags, Then in visual studio, You can select comment part and use <kbd>Ctrl + K + U</kbd> keys To remove comment. otherwise delete manually !